# Triggered Send from eCommerce using Marketing Cloud - Email Tracking in Service Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, triggered-send, marketing-cloud-connect

I configured a triggered send in Marketing Cloud choosing a Salesforce Data Extension as container of data sent through the API Call. This transactional email will be triggered from eCommerce after every contact's purchase.

At the same time I implemented MC Connector between Service Cloud and Marketing Cloud. The aim is to shown the email tracking results in the Individual Email Results tab in Service Cloud.

Using the SOAP API I sent the Contact ID (Salesforce ID) as SubscriberKey. The call doesn't fail and the email is sent, however I don't have any tracking results in Service Cloud. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: There are triggered sends in SC and MC. If you use the triggered send in SC the tracking data will come back down. If you use the triggered send in MC the tracking data will not automatically go to SC.

Comment: I supposed this behavior; but at the same time into the triggered email settings you can select a standard data extension or a salesforce data extension. I thought there was a different meaning depending on this choice, otherwise I don't understand why there is this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Jesse is correct triggered sends tracking are available only if sent via Salescloud. The work around is to send the email via journey builder and call the journey via API.